# List all posts in custom post type by taxonomy not working

Tags: javascript, php, wordpress, list

I am trying to get a list of all the posts in custom post type by taxonomy, I am stuck 3 days at this code, now i study with my father and he gave me a hint why my code is'nt working he a said i have too many args i will show you the code i hope anyone can help me understand why its not working and maybe if you really kind a explanation of the code in english

```
print_r(Array(
    "1"=>"first",
    "2"=>"second"
    ));
// just try to remove args that you don't need 
//actually you need only one
$args = array(
    'tax_query' => array(
            'taxonomy' => 'your-custom-taxonomy',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => array( 'your-term' )
    ),
    'post_type' => 'your-post-type'
);
$loop = new WP_Query($args);
     if($loop->have_posts()) {
    $term = $wp_query->queried_object;
     while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post();
        //Output what you want      
   echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></li>';
      endwhile;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

1. So you have a custom post type called `your-post-type`
2. and you have a custom taxonomy called `your-custom-taxonomy` and you
3. want to get all the posts with a taxonomy term set called `your-term`.

You are doing it the right way with setting your arguments.

**Notice**: If you want to get **all** the posts of a custom post type, you do not need the whole `'tax_query'` part of code.

I added some comments to describe what the code is doing:

```
$args = array( // define your arguments for query
    'post_type' => 'your-post-type', // standard post type is 'post', you use a custom one
    'tax_query' => array( // you check for taxonomy field values
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'your-custom-taxonomy', // standard is 'category' you use a custom one
            'field'    => 'slug', // you want to get the terms by its slug (could also use id)
            'terms'    => 'your-term', // this is the taxonomy term slug the post has set
        ),
    ),
);
$loop = new WP_Query( $args ); // get post objects

// The Loop
if ( $loop ->have_posts() ) { // check if you received post objects
    echo "<ul>"; // open unordered list
    while ( $loop ->have_posts() ) { // loop through post objects
        $loop ->the_post();
            echo '<li><a href="'.get_permalink().'">'.get_the_title().'</a></li>'; // list items
    }
    echo "</ul>"; // close unordered list
    /* Restore original Post Data */
    wp_reset_postdata(); // reset to avoid conflicts
} else {
    // no posts found
}
```

Hope this helps!

---

EDIT: **If you do not know how to use WP_Query**

This code will get your wordpress posts ordered by their titles and output title and content. Put this inside a template file of your theme (learn something about template files: https://developer.wordpress.org/themes/basics/template-hierarchy/).

```
<?php 

$args = array(
 'post_type' => 'post',
 'posts_per_page' => -1, // limit the number of posts if you like to
 'orderby' => 'title',
 'order' => 'ASC'
);

$custom_query = new WP_Query($args); 

if ($custom_query->have_posts()) : while($custom_query->have_posts()) : $custom_query->the_post(); ?> 
  <h1><?php the_title(); ?></h1> 
  <?php the_content();?>
<?php endwhile; else : ?> 
  <p>No posts</p>
<?php endif; wp_reset_postdata(); ?>
```

You said you want to use a custom post type and do a taxonomy query. So you can adjust this with changing the arguments in `$args`.

Comment: lets say i want the list to be something like this title will be galleries then 1-3 will be post 1 post 2 post 3(this is the name of my custom post typs

Comment: also it give me a eror whenever i tried to load the site, my code and the code you posted here

Comment: I do not understand what you are writing, I'm sorry. 'Post' is the normal way to publish posts in wordpress. You can add a custom post type, like in shops maybe 'products'. If you have a category term called 'galleries' you can add `category` in your args 'taxonomy' and check for the term by replacing `your_term` with`galleries`

Comment: I edited my answer to show you the basics of how to get posts in wordpress and display the title and content one by one. Hope it helps clear things out!

Comment: I still get eror when i load my site i have no idea way im new to wordpress